# What is the hidden meaning of electrochemical stability window?

Tags: electrochemistry

I don't really get the real meaning of the electrochemical stability window. I googled a lot, and the only thing I understand about the electrochemical stability window is that it's the voltage range that the substance is not oxidized and reduced. However, what does this term imply? I mean, I wonder that how we use this concept in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are confused by the word window, just like a window has a limited opening [=in a loose sense an interval], electrochemical stability window means the range where the solvent does not get oxidized or reduced. As explained by CH3M, you cannot scan water past 1.2 V vs SHE. It will begin to decompose electrolytically. Of course you have to see the context as well.

> I mean, I wonder that how we use this concept in practice.

In practice, you will look up the literature to find at what voltage a given solvent system begins to electrolyze. Basically you want your molecule to take part in the redox activity, not the medium in which your molecule of interest is present.

Comment: From your answer, can I conclude that electrode potential of the system should be within electrochemical window otherwise the electrolytes can be electrolytically decomposed?

Comment: Yes, this is partially correct. Not the electrolytes, but the medium which contains the redox species.

Comment: Do 'the redox species' that you mentioned mean those which are not my interest?

Comment: Redox species is the species is of your interest. The solvent or the medium is what we don't it to participate in reduction or oxidation.

Comment: Sorry for my poor understandings. So, you said that beyond the electrochemical window, not redox species, which are my interest, but other electrolytes which are not my interest ex) solvents can be decomposed?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct now. Suppose you are doing an electrochemical experiment, you have a species A dissolved in water. A can undergo redox reactions and water can also undergo redox reactions. During an experiment you only want A to undergo oxidation or reduction and study its behavior, but you do not want water to decompose. So you will not use potentials outside the stability window of water- if that makes it more clear.

Comment: I'm really, really thankful to you. So far, there is no place that can give real meaning of electrochemical window. By the way, when it comes to Li+/Li potential(-3.04V), many people mentioned its advantage of the most negative potential. But in my opinion, although most negative potential can generate high discharge voltage, it might be difficult to find proper electrolytes so that electrode potential should be within the electrochemical window of electrolytes because of high voltage. I wonder it is right to think in this way.

Comment: You are welcome. I had guessed that the term window is creating problems in your mind. Electrochemical window is a jargon and it is not an officially accepted term. Yes, lithium is a good example, but its redox system is outside the stability range of water. So you have to try another medium to try reducing lithium.

Answer (score 4):

The electrochemical stability window is most important when considering components of an electrochemical system that you **do not** want to be oxidized or reduced. This refers most often to the electrolyte or protective coatings.

For example, in lithium ion batteries it is highly desirable that the electrolyte does not react/change/degrade in any way as a result of battery charging/discharging or even in storage. A lithium ion battery typically has a voltage of 3.6 V. The electrolytes used are either lithium salts in organic solvents (ethylene carbonate, etc), solid ceramics, or polymerics electrolytes. If the electrolyte was water based, the electrochemical stability window would only be 1.2 V.

Why 1.2 V?

The standard reduction potential of water is 0.0 V (vs SHE)

The standard oxidation potential of water is 1.2 V (vs SHE)

You can not operate a 3.6 V lithium ion battery with an aqueous electrolyte because the electrolyte itself would react, creating dangerous hydrogen and oxygen gas. So you need an electrolyte with a larger stability window.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Can you check if I grasp the concept of electrochemical window after understanding your answer? As far as I know, electrochemical window can be calculated by subtracting reduction potential from the oxidation potential because the area between which reduction and oxidation potential has no reaction. (oxidation would happen when electrode potential is above reduction potential, while reduction would happen when electrode potential is below oxdiation potential)